# ajaxfileupload - how display a message during onuploadcomplete?

Tags: asp.net, upload, popup, ajaxcontroltoolkit, wait

I've got the AjaxFileUpload control working fine.

When the OnUploadComplete server side event is called, I'd like to be display a "wait" message while they are waiting.

```
protected void OnUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // does something very long
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: In what language? Please add the appropriate language tag.

Comment: In asp.net. The tags are ok now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OnClientUploadStart` property of AjaxFileUpload control for such functionality. See example here: [Codeplex - ACT Sample Web Site - AjaxFileUpload.aspx](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SampleWebSites/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx)

Comment: Ok, it’s working.

But is it possible to wait the end of the upload to display the message (when it shows 100%) ?

Because if I use onClientUploadStart, the message appear at start of the upload (0%).